# set UITextLayer text to a CATextLayer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-animation

I have a UIAlertView that asks for input and then the input is saved to a UITextField. I then want to be able to set the string of a CATextLayer to the text of the UITextField. I can NSLog the text in the text field to confirm it was set just fine like this:

```
NSLog (@"name = %@", nameTextField.text);
```

But if I try to use similar code to set the string of the CATextLayer:

```
[nameLayer setString:@"%@", nameTextField.text];
```

I get an error that says "Too many arguments to method call, expected 1, have 2". What do I need to do to set the string in the nameLayer to be the same as the text in the nameTextField?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `setString:` expects one argument any you're sending two: `@"%@"` and `nameTextField.text`.

You sould be doing `[nameLayer setString:nameTextField.text];` or even `nameLayer.string = nameTextField.text;`.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that it would count those as separate arguments. This worked like a charm, thank you!

Comment: @lunadiviner Yep, you were passing with the same syntax as something like `stringWithFormat:` which has an argument signature of `(NSString *)format, ...`